# How to add checkboxes in syncfusion pdf flutter?

Tags: flutter, pdf, checkbox

How to add checkboxes in pdf flutter?

- Syncfusion_flutter_pdf: ^20.3.58
- Flutter version is 3.0.2

Let me know if syncfusion forms are not free.

Code below is not visible in pdf I generate.

```
document.form.fields.add(PdfCheckBoxField(
document.pages.add(), 'CheckBox', Rect.fromLTWH(100, 200, 70, 45),
highlightMode: PdfHighlightMode.push,
borderStyle: PdfBorderStyle.dot,
borderColor: PdfColor(230, 0, 172),
backColor: PdfColor(153, 255, 102),
foreColor: PdfColor(255, 153, 0),
borderWidth: 1,
style: PdfCheckBoxStyle.diamond,
isChecked: true));
```

Source: https://help.syncfusion.com/flutter/pdf/working-with-forms#adding-the-check-box-field

Answer (score 0):

If your are using a "flattened" type of document, then they will not show.  Example, if your code reads as "page.graphics.drawString(" it is a flat style document.  You can write it like so:

```
document.form.fields.add(PdfCheckBoxField(page, 'checkbox', const Rect.fromLTWH(100, 100, 13, 13), borderWidth: 0, style: PdfCheckBoxStyle.check, isChecked: true));
```

Comment: Looks like you didn't finish your answer before you posted...? :)

Comment: I apologize the answer was cut off, but I went back and finished it for you.  Its been a long time and I never saw it